# how to random display data from table with a specific value

Tags: sql

I want that i random 5 data from my table but i want that the value "orange" is  always displayed in this random and "orange" also rand with them  , sow how to do that?

```
select fruits from table ORDER BY rand() limit 5;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select orange separately:

```
(select fruits from table where name = 'orange')
union all
(select fruits from table where name <> 'orange' order by rand() limit 4)
order by rand()
```

Comment: thanks bro but i want that my orange word olso rand with them @Salman A

Comment: the second rand() shuffles its position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using:

```
select t.fruits
from table t
order by (case when t.fruit = 'orange' then 1 else 2 end),
      rand()
limit 5;
```